# Generic way to call `getOrElse` on monads

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I am new to scala-cats library,
Initially I've created a generic code that combines monads according to a monoid I provide:

```
\\ implicitly uses cats catsDataMonoidForEither
Monoid[Either].combine(Right("foo"), Left(new NullPointerException))
\\ returns: Left(NullPointerException)

\\ implicitly uses a monoid that I provided
Monoid[Option[String]].combine(Some("foo"), Some("bar"), None)
\\ returns: Some("foobar")
```

The point is that I get different monads (I want to be able to handle `Validated` and `Try` too), and I am looking for a **generic** way to "getOrElse" them according to the pre-defined bias of <s>the monad</s> any FP abstraction, something like that:

```
def getOrEmpty[M, A](monad: M[A])(implicit monadM: Monad[M], monoidA[A]): A = {
    // Method "magicallyGetOrElse" is supposed to get a monad,
    // if its is the biased side (Some, Right etc.) return the value,
    // else return the monad's A
    monadM.magicallyGetOrElse(monad)(monoidA.empty)
```

How can I do it functionally?

Comment: You can't. The examples of monads you give (`Option`, `Either`, `Try` and `Validated`) have the particular property of being containers that hold exactly 0 or 1 "successful" values, but this isn't a general property of monads. Monad is a much broader concept - e.g. `List` (which contains arbitrarily many values), and `cats.effect.IO`, (which is a program that doesn't return a result until run) are monads, but `getOrElse` wouldn't be meaningful on them.

Comment: Is there any other functional abstraction that can help me do that?

Comment: I don't know of a ready-made one. My best suggestion would be to define a `ToOption[F[_]]` typeclass, and write instances for `Option` (that just returns the instance) and for `Either`, `Try` and `Validated` (that call `toOption` on values of the respective types). Then instead of using a `Monad[M]` instance in `getOrEmpty` you'd use a `ToOption[M]` instance.

Comment: So for the first one looks like that'd be `Applicative` for `Either[E, ?]` check out cats `mapN` function for a good example how this works. 

The second one is monoid derivation for any `Option[A]` where `A` has a monoid. 

as explained by Ben you can't combine Monads in general but emptyness can be represented.

ScalaZ has a typeclass `IsEmpty` which you could use, I don't know on top of my head for cats. 

Further `Validated` does not have a `Monad` instance. And can you maybe explaina bit more on what you're doing? I don't see the reason for the `Monad` constraint in your function

Comment: Looks a like [`Foldable#fold`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Foldable.html#fold[A](fa:F[A])(implicitA:cats.Monoid[A]):A) might be approximately what you want?

Comment: `Comonad` extracts value from the "container". So question is for which `F[_] ` comonad instance makes sense and how.

Comment: `Foldable#fold` definitely did the job, and luckily `Foldable` is implemented for `Option`, `Either` and `Try`.